# Reactive, long-running sequences and persistence in the cloud

Tags: azure, persistence, system.reactive

I am to build a kind of website tracking system. 
Think of a website where users click on various links – a unique user id and an identifier of the page tracks all page views.

Now, a single user might view 20 pages – some relevant some not. What I want to track is if a user follows a specific “path”. Example “Home Page” -> “Product A Page” -> “Get more info page” -> “Buy” -> “Paid”. There might be other page views in between each of these steps; the important thing is IF a user follows a given pattern. 
In addition, I need to measure time between each step (each page view has a timestamp).

I have been playing around with Reactive Extensions, but I am not an expert in the area so I would like to hear if this would be a job for the Reactive Framework or if other technologies are more suitable?

I imagine a server getting a stream of website page views and then some fancy reactive LINQ queries that captures the events (this is where I need some help).

Next question that comes to my mind is how do you host this behind a load-balancer (on Windows Azure)? If you run two instances and the “Home Page”-page view goes to instance 1 and “Product A Page” goes to instance 2, how do they communicate about this or should some kind of sharding e.g. per userid be enforced?

Lastly, what about persistence? How to store? Should you store data in an Event Queue pattern and then load everything into memory when you “play back” from a restart of the server?

I know that were many questions, but I do love the philosophy behind Reactive Extensions; I just cannot get my head around how to “put into production in the cloud” :)

Thanks!

Casper

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of solutions out there in this space already that you can integrate into your platform. Are you sure you're not reinventing the wheel? Google Analytics has functionality similar to this. If you need to go your own way, then SQL Server StreamInsight might be a better fit.

For behind-the-firewall solutions, Also look at http://piwik.org/ (free, open-source) and http://www.haveamint.com/.